# Removing a restriction site and introducing other at its place

Tags: dna, homework, genetics, cloning, restriction-enzymes

> What would you do if you want to **remove** an EcoRI restriction site
>   and introduce BamHI restriction site at apprx. the same location ?

One of the answers in my textbook was : To construct a DNA fragment with the structure:

```
5'AATTGGATCC3'
    3'CCTAGGTTAA5'
```

I understand that this would ligate efficiently to the sticky ends generated by EcoRI cleavage and would introduce a BamHI site but I don't understand how this will remove/not regenerate the EcoRI site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The recognition site for EcoRI is `GAATTC`, and the enzyme cuts after the first base. See this picture from [NEB](https://www.neb.com/products/r0101-ecori):

[image]

The overhang is: AATT, which is supplied by your oligo and fits into the overhang. If the next nucleotide whould be a `C` than the site would be recreated, since its a `G` its not. The new sequence of the old EcoRI site is `GGATTG` which is not recognized by EcoRI.

One technical note: To avoid religation of the digested DNA which carries this site, I would treat it with alkaline phosphatase to remove the phosphate end at the 5' end of the DNA.

Comment: I am still not able to understand how it destroys the EcoRI site. Sorry for being so slow !

Comment: Look at the sequences: EcoRI needs GAATTC to recognize and cut DNA. After the ligation with your BamHI oligo the sequence of the site is GAATT`G` so it cannot recognize the site anymore.

Comment: I get it now. I also understood why I couldn't figure it out at first - because I thought the RE just cares about G and A not any further sequence but now I understand that the whole sequence is important. THANKS A TON !

Answer (score 3):

Just in case you are having difficulty visualising what happens in the answer from @Chris, here are the steps with the linker shown in lower case

```
...NNNNNGAATTCNNNNN...           ds DNA
...NNNNNCTTAAGNNNNN...

          |
          V

...NNNNG          AATTCNNNNN...  after EcoRI digestion
...NNNNCTTAA          GNNNNN...

          |
          V

...NNNNG      aattggatcc        AATTCNNNNN...   incoming linker
...NNNNCTTAA      cctaggttaa        GNNNNN...    

          |
          V

...NNNNGaattggatccAATTCNNNNN...    after ligation
...NNNNCTTAAcctaggttaaGNNNNN...
```

The left hand "EcoRI" is now GAATTG and the right hand "EcoRI" is CAATTC.

Comment: I was wrong reading the sequence. Removed that part.